# symfony webpacke encore node-sass install error

Tags: symfony, webpack, node-sass

I am cloning the Symfony project form git repository. Project is using webpack encore.

```
git clone
composer install
npm install
```

but this produce error in node-sass[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved by running npm install by host machine, because composer install was running also in host machine

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild if npm package creates error

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: what is your node.js version?

Comment: may be conflict between versions, try updating node.js

Comment: its in docker container